# Split row into multiple based on percentages

Tags: database, ms-access

I have two  tables . I would like to **split** the  rows of data into new multiple records, with the fields calculated based on percentages listed in another table, and the results put into a query or new table.

Table 1:

```
ID       Value        Count
1        100           10
2        1000          100
```

Table 2:

```
ID        ID2         Percent
1         B            80%
1         C            20%
2         B            70%
2         D            30%
```

Output:

```
ID       ID2       Value        Count
1        B          80           8
1        C          20           2
2        B          700          70
2        D          300          30
```

I can do this manually in Excel, but the input in table 1 will change every month, so needless to say creating an automated way to do this is much more efficient.

Comment: Where is the data stored, e.g. is it in an Excel Spreadsheet, an SQL Server database, or a text file? How do you want to display this data, e.g. in a DataGrid, in a TextBox, or on a web form?

Comment: Both table 1 and table 2 are in MS Access tables, and I would like the output to either be a query result or new table of its own, within the MS access database

Answer (score 0):

I am making two assumpions about your data tables and view here.

1. The `Output`'s `Value` column is equal to `Table1`'s `Value` column multiplied by `Table2`'s `Percent` column
2. The `Output`'s `Count` column is equal to `Table1`'s `Count` column multiplied by `Table2`'s `Percent` column

I would also make one change to your database schema: in order to make the multiplication work better, I would change all of the percents to their decimal form to make them easier to work with. In Access, you will need to look at the `Percent` column in `Table2`'s design view, click `Field Size` in the bottom panel, and change it to `Double`.

I did this before writing the query below.

**Now, how to display what you want**:

I went to the Access database and created a new query. Once you are there, click the `View` toolbar or ribbon drop-down button and click `SQL View`. You can then use this code to produce your result:

```
SELECT Table2.ID, Table2.ID2, Table1![Value]*Table2!Percent AS [Value], [Table1]![Count]*[Table2]![Percent] AS Count
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID;
```

You may also want to change the name of your `Value` columns, as this is an Access reserved word, and could cause problems later.

When you execute the query, the results will be produced just like you had them in your example. You can then use this query to populate an application.